# Javascript: DOM problems

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

```
function a1() {
var newParagraph = document.createElement('div');
newParagraph.className = '"alert alert-success" role="alert"';
newParagraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<b>Richtig!  </b>Du scheinst dich um dein Wissen zu bemühen."));
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newParagraph);
window.setTimeout(partB,3000);
addText();
}
```

Hey there!, i am trying to create a interactive quiz. Instead of put a 'alert' as an answer i want to add an element on the Website which i picked its:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Richtig!  </b>Du scheinst dich um dein Wissen zu bemühen.</div>
```

this.

I want to add it after an parent div-tag called 'alarm' as a child.
It does not work why ?

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console?

Comment: `className = '"alert alert-success" role="alert"';`... that doesnt look like a proper className

Comment: They should make that console visible by default...

Comment: @PatrickEvans Its a Bootstrap claas. Yes i get the Error that addText is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function a1() {
  var newParagraph = document.createElement('div');
  newParagraph.className = 'alert alert-success';
  newParagraph.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
  newParagraph.innerHTML = '<b>Richtig!  </b>Du scheinst dich um dein Wissen zu bemühen.';
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newParagraph);
  window.setTimeout(partB, 3000);
  addText();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Richtig! </b>Du scheinst dich um dein Wissen zu bemühen.</div>

<a href='javascript: a1();' class='btn btn-primary'>Add</a>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: It erros out that addText(); is not defined.

Comment: @motoxdev I don't know, what you going to doing with `addText()` and `window.setTimeout(partB, 3000);`. Because, i cannot see that function implementations. If you don't need that so remove it.

Comment: function partB() {
    window.location.href = "quiz2.html";
    var punkte = +1;
}

Its just a delay